# Where do the different chest types (Bronze/Silver/Gold) come from?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

I've seen some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a28zgry_SyA) online that show chests being sold as Bronze, Silver and Gold hero chests. They also appear to be from the mobile version of the game still as well.

However, when I go into the store all I see in chests are Basic Chest and Hero Chest.

Where do these other chest types come from?

Comment: Side note: I didn't actually watch this video or the ones like it, just saw the thumbs and captions talking about gold chests etc. whilst searching for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who posted this video mentioned in the comments below the video that this video was created before a certain update that removed Bronze, Silver, and Gold chests. This can also been seen because there are no Bronze heroes in the game, just silver, gold and purple for legendary.

So there are no other types of hero boxes due to a recent update that changed that.

Comment: Ah should have looked into the comments, I only opened the video up to check the description and the link...